# Listening to Object changes within a List in JavaFX, in contrast to listening to List changes itself

Tags: java, arrays, list, javafx

The following code snippet listen to changes in `rectangles` (a list of rectangles ) and prints `event is invoked.` on screen whenever a `Rectangle` object is added to or removed from `rectangles`.

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle rectangle=new Rectangle(0,0,1,1);

        ObservableList<Rectangle> rectangles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        rectangles.addListener((ListChangeListener<Rectangle>) change ->
                System.out.println("event is invoked."));

        rectangles.addAll(rectangle);

    }
}
```

My question is whether it is possible to listen to changes in the objects in `rectangles` rather than listening to adding to or removing from `rectangles`. For example, the event should be invoked when I change the fill color of a `Rectangle` object in `rectangles`. I tried the following code (added a line of `rectangle.setFill(new Color(1,0,0,0.5));`) and expected to have `event is invoked.` printed twice, but it did not work.

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle rectangle=new Rectangle(0,0,1,1);

        ObservableList<Rectangle> rectangles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        rectangles.addListener((ListChangeListener<Rectangle>) change ->
                System.out.println("event is invoked."));

        rectangles.addAll(rectangle);
        rectangle.setFill(new Color(1,0,0,0.5));

    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a [listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393423/how-to-make-javafx-property-listener-to-fire-an-event-even-if-the-oldvaule-and-n) to any [JavaFX] property. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html) for the properties of `Rectangle`.

Comment: Create the list with an [extractor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `ObservableList` that fires change events to listeners when properties in the list's elements are changed by specifying an [extractor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)) when you create the list.

The extractor is a function which maps each element of the list to an array of `Observable` values which should be listened to for changes. If you want to know when the `fill` property of the rectangle in your list changes, you can do:

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle rectangle=new Rectangle(0,0,1,1);

        // create list with an extractor:
        ObservableList<Rectangle> rectangles = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(rect -> new Observable[] { rect.fillProperty()});

        rectangles.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Rectangle> change) ->
                System.out.println("event is invoked."));

        rectangles.addAll(rectangle);
        rectangle.setFill(new Color(1,0,0,0.5));

    }
}
```

Refer to the [`ListChangeListener.Change` API documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) for methods on the `change` object that allow you to determine what caused the listener to be invoked. For example:

```
    rectangles.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Rectangle> change) -> {
        while (change.next()) {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                System.out.println("Added " + change.getAddedSize() + " rectangle(s)");
            }
            if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                System.out.println("Removed "+change.getRemovedSize()+" element(s)");
            }
            if (change.wasUpdated()) {
                int from = change.getFrom();
                int to = change.getTo();
                System.out.println("Rectangle(s) from index "+from+" to "+to+" were changed");
            }
        }
    });
```

will generate the following output:

```
Added 1 rectangle(s)
Rectangle(s) from index 0 to 1 were changed
```